# R Tidy : Dynamic Sequential Threshold

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I'm trying to find a tidy way to dynamically adjust a threshold as I "move" through a tibble using `library(tidyverse)`. For example, imagine a tibble containing sequential observations:

```
example <- 
  tibble(observed = c(2,1,1,2,2,4,10,4,2,2,3))
example
# A tibble: 11 x 1
   observed
      <dbl>
 1        2
 2        1
 3        1
 4        2
 5        2
 6        4
 7       10
 8        4
 9        2
10        2
11        3
```

I'm trying to calculate a threshold that starts with the initial value (2) and increments by a prespecified amount (in this case, 1) unless the current observation is greater than that threshold in which case *the current observation* becomes the reference threshold and further thresholds increment from it. Here is what the final tibble would look like:

```
answer <- 
  example %>%
  mutate(threshold = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14))
answer
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   observed threshold
      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1        2         2
 2        1         3
 3        1         4
 4        2         5
 5        2         6
 6        4         7
 7       10        10
 8        4        11
 9        2        12
10        2        13
11        3        14
```

I'm looking for the best way to do this using dplyr/tidy. All help is appreciated!

EDIT:

The answers so far are very close, but miss in the case that the observed values drop and increase again. For example consider the same tibble as `example` above, but with a `4` instead of a `3` for the final observation:

```
example <- 
  tibble(observed = c(2,1,1,2,2,4,10,4,2,2,4))
example
# A tibble: 11 x 1
   observed
      <dbl>
 1        2
 2        1
 3        1
 4        2
 5        2
 6        4
 7       10
 8        4
 9        2
10        2
11        4
```

The diff & cumsum method then gives:

```
example %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(observed) > thresh))) %>%
  mutate(thresold = first(observed) + row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-gr)

A tibble: 11 x 2
   observed thresold
      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        2        2
 2        1        3
 3        1        4
 4        2        5
 5        2        6
 6        4        4
 7       10       10
 8        4       11
 9        2       12
10        2       13
11        4        4
```

Where the final threshold value is incorrect.

Comment: Can you check the values between 5 and 6.  it is greater than 1

Comment: @akrun - there is no stipulation that the observed values have to be <= 1 on sequential measurements

Comment: Your 6th row is not aligning with the threshold

Comment: It is correct as is, the threshold should continue incrementing unless the observed value is greater than the threshold.

Comment: The part `continue incrementing unless the observed value is greater than the threshold` is not clear to me.  The threshold is 1

Comment: Looking at my original `answer` tibble, notice as you move down the tibble the `threshold` value is incrementing by 1 `(2,3,4,...)`. Row number 7 would have a threshold value of `8`, but since the observed value of `10` is greater than `8` the threshold inherits the `10`. The threshold then continues to increment from `10` through to the end of the tibble `(11,12,13,14)`.

Comment: You can check my upddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `diff` to create groups and add row number in the group to the `first` value.

```
library(dplyr)
thresh <- 1

example %>%
   group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(observed) > thresh))) %>%
   mutate(thresold = first(observed) + row_number() - 1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-gr)

# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   observed thresold
#      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1        2        2
# 2        1        3
# 3        1        4
# 4        2        5
# 5        2        6
# 6        4        4
# 7       10       10
# 8        4       11
# 9        2       12
#10        2       13
#11        3       14
```

---

To understand how the groups are created here are the detailed steps :

We first calculate the difference between consecutive values

```
diff(example$observed) 
#[1] -1  0  1  0  2  6 -6 -2  0  1
```

Note that `diff` gives output of length 1 less than the actual length.

We compare it with `thresh` which gives `TRUE` for every time we have value greater than the threshold

```
diff(example$observed) > thresh
 #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now since output of `diff` has one value less we add one value as `TRUE`

```
c(TRUE, diff(example$observed) > thresh)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and then finally take `cumsum` to create groups which is used in `group_by`.

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(example$observed) > thresh))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

---

**EDIT**

For the updated question we can add another condition to check of the previous value is greater than the current count and update the values accordingly.

```
example %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(observed) > thresh) & 
                observed > first(observed) + row_number())) %>%
  mutate(thresold = first(observed) + row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-gr)

# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   observed thresold
#      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1        2        2
# 2        1        3
# 3        1        4
# 4        2        5
# 5        2        6
# 6        4        7
# 7       10       10
# 8        4       11
# 9        2       12
#10        2       13
#11        4       14
```

Comment: This seems to provide exactly the result I want. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(observed) > thresh))` command is doing, though. Do you have a link you could share that may explain it?

Comment: @colton I added some explanation on that line.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually solves the issue. For example, consider if the last observed value is a 4 instead of a 3. The threshold ends up decreasing instead of incrementing on the last value. I've updated my description to include this example.

Comment: @colton If last value is 4, the difference is greater than threshold hence a new group is created from there. Threshold value for each group is first value in the group + row number. What output would you expect in that case?

Comment: The threshold should never decrease as observations continue, as shown in my original answer tibble. The threshold continually increases by the prespecified amount (1), unless an observed value is greater in which case the threshold increases to that observed value.

Comment: @colton Can you check my updated answer after **EDIT** ?

Answer (score 1):

We can create the grouping variable with `lag` of the column difference

```
library(dplyr)
thresh <- 1
example %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum((observed - lag(observed, default = first(observed)) >
             thresh))) %>%
   mutate(threshold = observed[1] + row_number()  - 1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
          mutate(new = row_number() + 1, 
    threshold = pmax(threshold, new)) %>%     
   select(-grp, -new)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   observed threshold
#      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        2         2
# 2        1         3
# 3        1         4
# 4        2         5
# 5        2         6
# 6        4         7
# 7       10        10
# 8        4        11
# 9        2        12
#10        2        13
#11        3        14
```

Comment: This answer seems very close, but fails in the case, for example, that the final observed value is a `4` rather than a `3`. (It finds the final threshold as `12` rather than `14`).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out a way to do this, by utilizing zoo::locf (although I'm not sure this part is really necessary).

First create the harder of the two examples I've listed in my description:

```
example2 <- 
  tibble(observed = c(2,1,1,2,2,4,10,4,2,2,4))

example2 %>%
  mutate(def = first(observed) + row_number() - 1) %>%
  mutate(t1 = pmax(observed,def)) %>%
  mutate(local_maxima = ifelse(observed == t1,t1,NA)) %>%
  mutate(groupings = zoo::na.locf(local_maxima)) %>%
  group_by(groupings) %>%
  mutate(threshold = groupings + row_number() - 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-def,-t1,-local_maxima,-groupings)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   observed threshold
      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1        2         2
 2        1         3
 3        1         4
 4        2         5
 5        2         6
 6        4         7
 7       10        10
 8        4        11
 9        2        12
10        2        13
11        4        14
```

I'd definitely prefer a more elegant solution if anyone finds one.